# is i possible to bypass the checking of uploaded file via is_uploaded_file()?

Tags: php, file-upload

i need to upload file without using a form. i need to do this to make automated upload if a user click a button...

i have create $_FILES['thefile']['name'] and  $_FILES['thefile']['tmp'] but it still not working. is it possible to do uploading without a form ?

btw, i use wordpress. and wp use is_uploaded_file() to check whether the file a copy is an uploaded file or not.

Comment: `i have create $_FILES['thefile']['name'] and $_FILES['thefile']['tmp']` - php runs on the server. Altering $_FILES doesn't make the client _send_ the data. It's the other way round: _If_ the client sends multipart/form-data data _then_ php will fill $_FILES with the appropriate elements. I.e. you have to "convince" the client to send the data.

Comment: @vokerk do you have reference on how to convince the client to send the data ? i really need to understand this technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array $_FILES fills only where we use form with input element of "file" type.

Answer (score 2):

For security reasons this isn't allowed. You could embbed a java applet or flash to upload a file.